# Search Google by year

Tags: google-search, search-engine

I would like to know how I can tell Google to only show results from a specific year. I know many of the Google queries like `site:example.com` but I don't know how to Google by year as in e.g. `year:2018`?

Comment: The only way to do it (rather not older than a year) which I know is to search as is, then add `&as_qdr=y` into the address and re-search. Or use Advanced search page `https://www.google.ru/advanced_search`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin wonderful, do you mind to share it?

Comment: HINT: It's off-topic for [su]. But try looking at the options _after_ you do a basic search - specifically, what happens if you click on TOOLS, and then ANY TIME?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin love your tone, slightly ironic. But I'm trying to ask for a search term as in `site:example.com`. Yours does the job too though.

Answer (score 4):

OK, it's off-topic here, but it can be migrated with an answer intact...

1. Type search term & hit Enter
2. Click Tools
3. Click Custom...
4. Enter date range [click the calendar or type the dates]

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you know about any way to do it as a search term within basic search? Like I stated in my OP.

Comment: A search of Google suggests that the Google Search Query Language does not support this functionality; everything I can find recommends the method in this answer (which was also my comment to the question). I really do think it's bad form to answer a question that's off-topic for a particular stack, even if it _can_ be migrated together with answers.

Answer (score 2):

or you can append this to your URL:

```
&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A

 2018

 %2Ccd_max%3A

 2018
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option you can load Google with https://www.google.com/webhp?as_qdr=y1. I have 3 Google search bookmarks:

- https://www.google.com/ [basic]
- https://www.google.com/webhp?as_qdr=m3  [within the past 3 months]
- https://www.google.com/webhp?as_qdr=y1  [within the past year]

I generally always use the within the year one.